# Can we point kubernetes to another cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, kubectl

I have asked myself this question and invested time researching it. Running out of time. Can someone point me in the right direction?
I have created a kubernetes cluster on minikube, with its Ingress, Services and Deployments. There is a whole configuration of services in there. 
Can, now, I point this kubectl command to another provider like VMWareFusion, AWS , Azure, not to forget Google Cloud.
I know about kops. My understanding is that although this is the design goal of kops but presently it only supports AWS.

Comment: What do you mean by "point". You can configure `kubectl` to manage multiple clusters - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration

Comment: Thanks for that. This is very userful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use different clusters via the [context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/). List them using `kubectl config get-contexts` and switch between them using `kubectl config use-context`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you couple of things the way i worked out with kubernetes, From my local system to production my environment remains consistent.

I use kubeadm to create a kubernetes cluster on my local machine. And I maintain all my kubernetes resources like **Services, Pods, Deployment etc**.. in a yaml as my deployment files.

- All my services and pods are saved in a yaml file e.g. **counter.yaml**

```
    kind: Deployment
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    metadata:
      name: deployment-counter
      namespace: default
      labels:
        module: log-counter
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          module: log-counter
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            module: log-counter
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: container-counter
            image: busybox
            command:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
            - 'i=0; while true; do echo "$i: $(date)"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done'
            imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: Always
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          tolerations:
            - key: ud_application
              operator: Equal
              value: docxtract
              effect: NoSchedule
            - key: ud_module
              operator: Exists
              effect: NoSchedule
      strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
```

On my local kubernetes cluster provisioned by kubeadm I deploy it as follow

```
kubectl apply -f counter.yaml
```

And on Production i have a kubernetes cluster provisioned by kubeadm too and i deploy it the same way.
    kubectl apply -f counter.yaml

### PS:

**kubeadm** is a tool provided by kubernetes to provision a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: This is perfect too. Thanks. I wanted to accept both answers. But that is not possible. This is a great solution to transfer configuration from dev to production. Only I despaired of creating a local cluster on my Mac. I have gotten so far as to discover that local cluster is only created on Linux, not on Windows or Mac.